# How can access Keystone Mongodb database using robomongo

Tags: keystonejs

How can access Keystone Mongodb database using robomongo or terminal?

Is there any config set db url, username and password?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You configure the Keystonejs settings for Mongodb via:

- process.env.MONGO_URL (for a generic env variable)
- process.env.MONGOLAB_URL (for auto heroku config w/ MongoLab)
- mongodb://localhost/{project name as key}

So if you are running locally for development it it is most likely just at  mongodb://localhost/{project name as key}

There is an old issue on Github about this [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/124). Each of my projects have a database on my local Mongodb server.